# Sub queries or OUTER joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

which one has better performance?

```
SELECT *,(SELECT MAX(old) FROM employee WHERE employee.CompanyId = Company.Id)
    FROM Company
```

or

```
SELECT *,MAX(old) FROM Company LEFT OUTER JOIN employee
        ON Company.Id = employee.CompanyId
```

?

```
how about bigger queries ?
```

thank you

Comment: Have you tested your queries to find out for yourself?

Comment: Test it, measure it, profile it, EXPLAIN it, "Execution Query Plan" it ...

Comment: Try them both in management studio with the statistics and execution plans turned on and you will see which is quickest.  Why guess when you can test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run both queries in SQL Server Management Studio and look at the [execution plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx).

The execution plan will not only tell you which part of the query took how much resources, but also which of the two queries took more resources than the other (if you run the both together, the execution plan shows values in percent).

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to [read execution plans](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans) then have a look at that. A guess is that SQL Server will optimize both queries to the same execution plan anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery has generally lower performance than JOIN queries.